# Everything is rendered black, when I set it to be a gradient

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Hi I'm trying to render my file to be a gradient (cubes) and the floor to be glossy black.  I was following this tutorial on youtube (without the wireframe effect) and I can't figure out why this is happening.  The tutorial is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r5b8LaniMQ

You can see my blender file here: h[ttp://www.pasteall.org/blend/38973](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38973)

Answer (score 2):

The gradient material isn't assigned to any of the cubes; they just have a default diffuse material:

[image]

To assign your gradient material to all of them:

1. Select all the cubes (I used border select (<kbd>B</kbd>) to do this)
2. Set the material of the active object in *Properties > Materials*
3. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Materials* to link the active object's materials to the selected objects.

[image]

Comment: I tried doing all of that and the screen went completely black (well in the view in Blender).  After i pressed control Z

Comment: Just got it!  For some reason I didn't select the materials from "browse materials" button.  I guess if I select another way, it doesn't truly select the object.  Just had to follow your instructions exactly lol.  Thanks gandalf3!